# Resize cells in Google Spreadsheet programatically in php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Is there a way that we could resize the height and width of the cell in the Google spreadsheet, programatically, I am not sure about any of the php class given in Google sdk api to fulfill this requirement. I have found "google spreadsheet class" but didn't find where to download that class and how to use its functions in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spreadsheets API doesn't allow visual changes to the spreadsheets, it's a data API.